# Transparency in boxplot legend keys using R and ggplot2

Tags: r, transparency, ggplot2, legend, boxplot

I am trying to make boxplots with a transparent fill and a corresponding legend. The plotting with alpha values works fine except that the legend keys do not have transparent fills. The following example illustrates the difficulty:

```
dat <- data.frame(x=c('a', 'b', 'c'), y = runif(300), z = c('d', 'e', 'e'))
ggplot(dat) + geom_boxplot(aes(x, y, fill = z, colour = z), alpha = 0.2)
```

[image: Boxplot with transparencies in fill, but not int the legend]

Is there a way to make the fill values in the legend keys transparent too?

```
SessionInfo()
R version 2.14.0 (2011-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0/x86_64 (64-bit)
ggplot2_0.8.9
```

Thanks in advance for any tips on this issue.

An example where the alpha mapping works is the following

```
ggplot(dat) + geom_point(aes(x, y, fill = z, colour = z, shape = z), alpha = 0.2)
```

[image: Plot where alpha mapping works fine]

Comment: I deleted my answer in the light of khoske's comments and your counter example.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra -- Could you undelete your answer, so we can see khoske's comments?  Also, if the comments show why this **can't** be done, you could incorporate that in the top of your answer, and then it could be voted up and hopefully accepted by yellowcap.

Comment: Please submit a bug report at https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues

Answer (score 1):

The solution I've used in the past is this one... its a huge hack but works.

```
dat <- data.frame(x=c('a', 'b', 'c'), y = runif(300), z = c('d', 'e', 'e'))
dummy <- dat
dummy$z <- factor(dummy$z)
dummy <- dummy[1,]
dummy[,2]<-NaN
ggplot() + 
geom_boxplot(data=dat,aes(x, y, fill = z, colour = z), alpha = 0.2,legend=FALSE) +
geom_density(data=dummy,aes(x, fill = z, colour = z), alpha = 0.2)
```

I usually use it when I'm making a geom_text plot, but want the legend to show as points or blocks.  But it works for this instance too.

In case Hadley is paying attention to this thread, I've found myself wanting a plot=T/F option that works like the legend option for this situation.